# Microsoft Access - Get UserName and store in a table

Tags: ms-access, vba

I made a table to store which users open a database and when. I have a function to get the usernames in the VBA already since some forms are restricted.

How do I get all usernames stored in the new table along with a time stamp?

Thanks!

I want to track who uses a database, and when they login. That's it. I have a table set up to store the usernames and the timestamp for when someone opens the database

I have the code to get usernames when the database is opened, and it compares to an admin list I have in a table. That code is

```
Option Compare Database

Declare Function GetUserName& Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias "GetUserNameA" (ByVal lpBuffer As String, nSize As Long)

Public Function UserName() As String

    Dim str As String
    Dim lng As Long

        str = String$(200, 0)
        lng = 199

        If GetUserName(str, lng) Then
            UserName = Left$(str, lng - 1)
        End If

End Function
```

Comment: Can you expand on what you're trying to do?  Are you trying to write a query?  Put this info in a report?  On a form?  Trying to open the table?

Comment: It's very unclear what you are asking?  Maybe post an example, give some code you already have?  What is the specific problem you are encountering?

Answer (score 1):

Create an empty form called "Splash" and make this the form that opens when you open the database (Options->Current Database->Display Form)

Put this code in the Form_Open Event. This will load the screen whenever someone opens the db, insert a record into a table called LoginRecord and then close the form. The action is invisible to the user. Adjust the table/field names in the code to fit your situation.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO LoginRecord (UserName, LoginTime) VALUES ('" & Environ("Username") & "','" & Now() & "')"
    DoCmd.Close acForm, "Splash"
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
End Sub
```

Comment: good answer, but should use parameters, like here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52811565/78522