# Check for duplicate entries before adding data to access database

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

Using vbscript i am trying to add data to access database.  I am successfully able to add data to database but i want to check duplicity before adding data to database.

Duplicity should check in column Name, Phone and Id if found duplicity in any of these three column then show message found duplicity.

Below is the code which help me to add data to database.

```
sub addUser
    SQL_query = "INSERT INTO dvd (timestammp,Name,Phone,Id,Cat,StartDate,agent,amount,source,conver) VALUES ('"& txtteNow.value &"','"& txtName.value &"','"& txtPhone.value &"','"& txtId.value &"','"& txtCat.value &"','"& txtStartDate.value &"','"& txtsrch.value &"','"& txtamount.value &"','"& txtsource.value &"','"& txtconver.value &"')"
    conn.Execute(SQL_query
end sub
```

I try below code also but not working.

```
SQL_query = "INSERT INTO dvd (timestammp,Name,Phone,Id,Cat,StartDate,agent,amount,source,conver) VALUES('"& txtteNow.value &"','"& txtName.value &"','"& txtPhone.value &"','"& txtId.value &"','"& txtCat.value &"','"& txtStartDate.value &"','"& txtsrch.value &"','"& txtamount.value &"','"& txtsource.value &"','"& txtconver.value &"') WHERE NOT EXISTS (Select '2' from dvd  where Name = + " & txtName.value & + "
conn.Execute(SQL_query)
```

Comment: Try INSERT on CONFLICT

Comment: Hi  krithikaGopalakrisnan thanks for the reply.I am new to sql i have no clue how to use INSERT on CONFLICT.

Comment: INSERT ... ON CONFLICT is not available for Access SQL

Comment: The code looks like [tag:vbscript] but the accepted answer is [tag:vba] so have edited the tags to reflect this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is quite elaborate: use an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` query from a dummy table containing one record, then use a `NOT EXISTS` in there.

I'm going to use parameters too, you really should've done that yourself to avoid problems with SQL injection.

`CurrentDb` in this scenario is a DAO database object.

I'm going to only use 3 fields to keep the solution concise.

```
With CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("", "INSERT INTO dvd (timestammp,Name,Phone) " & _ 
    " SELECT p1, p2, p3" & _
    " FROM (SELECT First(ID) FROM MSysObjects) As Dummy" & _
    " WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM dvd WHERE Name = p1)"
    .Parameters("p1") = txtteNow.value
    .Parameters("p2") = txtName.value
    .Parameters("p3") = txtPhone.value
    .Execute
End With
```

Comment: For the benefit of others, this answer is using MSAccess VBA, not VBScript. `CurrentDb` is a built-in object in MSAccess and can only be used inside a DAO aware application like MSAccess.

Comment: @Lankymart I clarified: _CurrentDb in this scenario is a DAO database object._ In VBScript, you can lead with `Set CurrentDb = CreateObject("DAO.DBEngine.120").OpenDatabase("C:\Path\To\File.accdb")`.  I chose the name `CurrentDb` for the database object to make the code easy to use in VBA as well (since I suspected OP might actually be using VBA). I did make a mistake with the bang notation, fixed that.

Comment: That is true, but seeing as though the other recent questions by the same OP refer to VBScript style code (no type declarations) and make reference to `ADODB.Connection` I would suggest they are not using VBA. The simple fact is the question technically isn't clear enough to answer, but they accepted it regardless, be it blindly.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just try adding **Unique Indexes** to Name, Phone and Id ?
This way the database engine will discard those records automagically.
Possible drawback: you will not know which record has been dropped.